# jquery and json ajax....how to parse the data

Tags: javascript, json, jquery

Below is my jquery ajax call.  I see from fire bug that I am getting the json response.

```
   Content-Type application/json
   {x:1363590711.97,y:0.277528026651}
```

However...I cant event pop up and alert of the data?  How do I get the parsed json object so i cna start working iwth it?

```
$.ajax({
      type: 'GET',
      url: 'ajax_test',
      crossDomain: false,
      dataType: 'json',
      success: function(responseData) { 
          alert(responseData);
          //seriesJsonData[0]['data'].push({y: responseData.y, x: responseData.x});
      }
});
```

Comment: Your responseData should be JSON already, so responseData.x should respond with 1363590711. Use console.log(reponseData) to see the object in your console.

Comment: alert(responseData.x) / alert(responseData.y)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your return data is already parsed when you request dataType: 'json'

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'ajax_test',
    crossDomain: false,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(responseData) { 
          alert(responseData.x + " " + responseData.y);
          seriesJsonData[0]['data'].push(responseData);
    }
});
```